# como crear estos botones con C# en .net?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, .net

Alguien sabe como puedo hacer botones que despleguen una lista como se ven en esta imagen

[image: t]

Comment: Prueba con el MenuStrip, es muy intuitivo de usar y puedes añadirle imágenes a los botones.

Comment: pude personalizar el MenuStrip, gracias!!